# Constructor call flow with inheritance with C++

Tags: c++

I have a basic question with the flow of constructors w.r.t. inheritance in C++.
The classes are defined as follows:

Base class A is defined as follows. It has 2 constructors - **A()** and **A(int x)**. **A(int x)** calls **A()**.

```
class A {
protected:
    int a;

public:
    A() {
        a = 0;
    }

    A(int x) {
        A();
        a = x;
    }
};
```

Derived class B is derived from Base class A. It has 2 constructors - **B()** and **B(int x, int y)**.

- **B()** calls **A()** in addition to setting member variable b to 0.
- ***B(int x, int y)*** calls **A(x)**

```
class B : public A {
protected:
    int b;

public:
    B() : A() {
        b = 0;
    }

    B(int x, int y) : A(x) {
        B();
        b = y;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "a=" << a << ",b=" << b << std::endl;
    }

};
```

```
int main() {
    B b(1, 2);
    b.print();
}
```

**Output:**
a=1,b=2

**Expected:**
a=0,b=2

I am expecting the flow as below,

```
B b(1, 2) ->
B(int x=1, int y=2) ->
A(int x=1) ->
A() sets a=0 ->
A(int x=1) sets a = 1 ->
B() ->
A() overwrites a=0 ->   <===== Shouldn't a=0 get reflected in final output ?
B() sets b = 0 ->
B(int x=1, int y=2) sets b = 2
```

However, I am seeing a=1 and b=2.

***Does anyone know what is that I am missing in this code flow?***

#EDIT:#
Perhaps the better way to do this is as @Jarod42 suggested. The code is updated below. It is still unclear how come the above code is able to get a=1 and b=2. Dry runs indicate that we should be getting a=0 and b=2.

```
class A {
protected:
    int a;

public:
    A() : A(0) {

    }

    A(int x) {
        a = x;
    }
};


class B : public A {
protected:
    int b;

public:
    B() : B(0, 0) {

    }

    B(int x, int y) : A(x) {
        b = y;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "a=" << a << ",b=" << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: `A();` and `B();` creates an unnamed temporary object that immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: I wonder why you are trying to use different syntax for identical things. You write `A(int x) calls A()` as `A(int x) { A(); ...` (which is a correct syntax for some languages other than C++) but `B() calls A()` as `B() : A() {` (which happens to be the correct syntax in C++). Have you tried to write `A(int x) : A()` and got a compilation error? If so, your compiler is too old.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. : My compiler is VS2019. I think that this has to do with my lack of understanding of the language than the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
A(int x) {
    A(); ...
```

you have to delegate to the other constructor with :

```
A(int x) : A() {
     ...
```

Same within class B. Hope this solves your question.

Comment: In fact, it should be the other way: :`A() : A(0) {}` (especially for `B`).

Comment: Can you please check whether the code flow I have added is right w.r.t. constructor calls for the code added in the original post?

Comment: @Jarod42 : Thank you for your advice. With this the code got simplified and it makes more sense. `code` public:
    B() : B(0, 0) {

    }

    B(int x, int y) : A(x) {
        b = y;
    }

Comment: @user15043925: even better `B(int x, int y) : A(x), b(y) {}`.